# SQL: Need help query Construction between 2 Tables

Tags: mysql

I am in need of some help in constructing this sql query.
This is my test user table. it is connected to the department table through the 
**DeptID**

The situation is this, a user will request something and will be in need of approval by another **Approving user** which is stored in the **Authentication Table**.
The requests will be stored in the **Requests table** and will have a status of **Not Approved** until it is approved by the approving user.
What I need to do is create an sql query to find all the requests in the request table which has an **approved** status and is filtered from the **Authentication Table**

For example If i were to enter the **UserID** of Rose which is 3 I'll be seeing the requests **Soap** and **Pen** since she is assigned in the Maintenance and the Executive department found in the **Authentication Table**. And also if I were to enter the **UserID** of Jennifer which is 2 I'll only be seeing the request **Candy** since she is assigned in the Guidance Department in the Authentication Table.

I could only filter the requests via the **Request Status** Approved but not when connected with the **Authentication Table** already.

```
SELECT u.ReqID, u.ReqName, d.dept_name,u.ReqStatus 
FROM Request u,Department d 
where u.DeptID = d.DeptID AND u.ReqStatus = 'Approved'
```

This is the SQL Fiddle link : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16b0a/1)

Thanks.

[image]

This is my Department Table

[image]

This is my Requests Table

[image]

This is my Authentication Table

[image]

Comment: The tables in the sqlfiddle are very different from the ones in the question. There's no `dept_name` column in the `Requests` and `Authentication` table, and no `name` column in `Auth`. Very confusing.

Comment: every table is connected by their primary keys. Table names can be seen through the SQL Fiddle link @Barmar thanks for your previous answer I was able to make it work with a simple adjustment :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use JOINs. They are more efficient.

If you want this fields

```
u.ReqID, u.ReqName, d.dept_name,u.ReqStatus
```

Use this query

```
SELECT u.ReqID, u.ReqName, d.dept_name,u.ReqStatus
FROM Request u INNER JOIN Department d ON u.DeptID = d.DeptID
WHERE u.ReqStatus Like 'Approved'
```

If you want the name of users use this query.

```
SELECT u.ReqID, u.ReqName, d.dept_name,u.ReqStatus, a.UserID, us.name
FROM Request u INNER JOIN Department d ON u.DeptID = d.DeptID
INNER JOIN Auth a ON u.DeptID = a.DeptID INNER JOIN Users us
ON a.UserID = us.UserID
WHERE u.ReqStatus Like 'Approved'
```

Sorry, i forget, if you want it a specific user, use this query:

```
SELECT u.ReqID, u.ReqName, d.dept_name,u.ReqStatus, a.UserID, us.name
FROM Request u INNER JOIN Department d ON u.DeptID = d.DeptID
INNER JOIN Auth a ON u.DeptID = a.DeptID INNER JOIN Users us
ON a.UserID = us.UserID
WHERE u.ReqStatus Like 'Approved' AND a.UserID = 2
```